# How to query dynamic fields from mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, mongotemplate

I have a mongoDb collection with following data:

```
{
 "material_name": "david",
 "material_unit": "87",
 "version": "1.0"
}
```

I am using following query field filter to fetch all material related fields which is working alright.

```
Query query = new Query();
query.fields().include("material_name");
query.fields().include("material_unit");
```

I have almost 100+ fields names which start with material. Is it possible to query fields with some kind of regex or any alternative approach?.

E.g.

```
Query query = new Query();
query.fields().include("material*");
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the more efficient way is this one:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   { $set: { data: { $objectToArray: "$$ROOT" } } },
   {
      $set: {
         data: {
            $filter: {
               input: "$data",
               cond: { $regexMatch: { input: "$$this.k", regex: "^material" } }
            }
         }
      }
   },
   { $replaceWith: { $arrayToObject: "$data" } }
])
```

You can also filter one the values like `cond: { $eq: [ "$$this.v", "david" ] }`